# How do I get my missing Fitness badges from my old iphone to my new iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, applications, fitness+

I backed up my old iphone onto my laptop, then restored everything from my laptop onto my new iphone.  My apps, contacts, photos, podcasts, etc. seems to have transferred over.  However, when I looked at my Apple Fitness app, all my badges, previous activity data are all missing from the app.  How can I copy/transfer this data from my old phone to my new phone?  Shouldn't this data have been transferred with the backup?

Comment: Is the new phone registered with Apple Fitness

Comment: No?  It still has the ad that says I have 3 free months of Fitness+.  On my old phone, Fitness+ appeared one day when I updated to ios 15 or 16 but I don't think I had to sign up for Fitness and it kept my badges, progress, activity, etc.

Comment: So it does not know you are on a new phone

Comment: No, doesn’t seem like it 

Comment: can yu still access it on old phone

Comment: I was the last time I checked but the last time I checked, the old phone was still connected to my apple ID.  I have since removed that device so who knows if it can see it.  And in case you were thinking of using icloud, I only have the 5GB intro limit and I didn't know how to upload just my health info via icloud and I still feel the data should have come from the laptop backup.